# Golang lib to mock mysql database in-memory

Tags: open-source, software-testing, unit-tests, go, mocks

Does someone know's a lib like this one or similar, but more updated?
https://github.com/proullon/ramsql

I need a lib to mock a Mysql table so i can implement on my automated tests.

This lib would fit perfectly but it doesn't implement some lexeme from the sql such as sql aliases, some mysql built-in functions.

Comment: Probably not the same and a bit too heavy but what if you start a docker container with a mysql database?

Comment: @jmizv It would work but it would take a long time to process tests and i would have to manually clean my database after each test to keep an isolated test environment.

Comment: I've used this lib https://github.com/dolthub/go-mysql-server and it work perfectly.

Comment: Maybe you can add this as an answer to your own question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging and researches I've endup using this lib https://github.com/dolthub/go-mysql-server and it works perfectly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).